# Pole and residue of trigonometric function

Tags: complex-analysis

Good evening, I want to check my answers regarding calculations.

So, the function is $\frac{sin(z^2)}{z^3}$

Pole at $z^3$, order of 3 and its equal to zero.

To find residue, I need to expand sin function in the numerator.

Since sin(z) = z - $\frac{z^3}{3!}$ + $\frac{z^5}{5!}$ - ..., then

$sin(z^2)$ = $z^2$ - $\frac{z^6}{3!}$ + $\frac{z^{10}}{5!}$-....

Thus, $z^2$ - $\frac{z^6}{3!}$ + $\frac{z^{10}}{5!}$ over $z^3$ will give us $\frac{1}{z}$ - $\frac{z^3}{3!}$ + ... Therefore, the order of the pole is 1 and residue is  $-\frac{1}{6}$?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the definition of residue?

Comment: Good evening. From Laurent expansion we have f(z) = sigma(bn/(z-z0)^n + sigma(an(z-zo)^n. The residue its b1/(z-z0). So, I assume it's second value, after the order?

Comment: Why are you assuming that?  That isn't the [definition of residue.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_(complex_analysis)#Definition)

Comment: Hm, I use material from this notes: [link](https://math.mit.edu/~jorloff/18.04/notes/topic8.pdf)

Comment: You aren't looking at the examples very closely then.  The residue is $b_1$, which in this case is $1$.  Look at the top of page $6$ for example.  Also look at section 8.4.2 for residues at higher-order poles.

Comment: Damn! I thought you need to include factorial in the denominator as well. Thank you so much!

Comment: You are looking at the wrong term.  It's the ${1\over z}$ term that determines the residue.  Look at the examples again.  They're talking about ${b_1\over z-z_0}$.  The $z^3$ term has nothing to do with it.

Comment: "Pole at $z^3$" No! Pole at $z=0$. "and it's equal to zero" ?? *What*, exactly, is equal to zero? Please use the words to mean what they mean, and not something sorta kinda like what they mean, or you'll never escape your confusions and uderstand what's going on.

Comment: To Gerry Myerson, I see, sorry about that. Then if we have an example, like $\frac{z}{(z^2)(z-1)}$, there is pole at z=0, and pole at z=1? To saulspatz, thank you for the clarification. I saw similar process for $\frac{sinz}{z^2}$, where the residue is 1 as well.

Comment: Yes, poles at $z=0$ and $z=1$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{\sin z^2}{z^3} = \frac{1}{z^3} \left (z^2 - \frac{z^6}{3!} + \frac{z^{10}}{5!} + \dots \right ) = \frac{1}{z} + \frac{z^3}{3!} + \frac{z^{7}}{5!} + \dots$$

Look at the coefficient on $\frac{a_{-1}}{z}$, it is $1$. Therefore $\text{Res}\left ( \frac{\sin z^2}{z^3}, 0\right) = 1$. This is is a simple pole.